# Spree routes: Adding only the api routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, spree

When I add the following to the routes

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
```

it adds all the spree routes to my application but I want only the `api` routes to be added to the application. What changes should I do for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spree is split into `spree_core`, `spree_backend`, `spree_frontend`, `spree_api`, `spree_sample` and `spree_cmd`.

From the [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) `README`

```
spree_api (RESTful API)
spree_frontend (User-facing components)
spree_backend (Admin area)
spree_cmd (Command-line tools)
spree_core (Models & Mailers, the basic components of Spree that it can't run without)
spree_sample (Sample data)
```

Each component appends its own set of routes to the `Spree::Core::Engine` with `add_routes`. There is a bit of overlap, for instance `spree_api` includes some `admin` [routes](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/api/config/routes.rb#L2-L9). With that said, you would still use the same mounting method.

```
# config/routes.rb
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
```

However, you would select the Spree components individually instead of the all-inclusive `spree` gem that includes all routes from all components.

For example:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'spree_api'
```